# CSS: ¿por qué la imagen no ocupa el 100% del ancho de la página?

Tags: html, css, imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un problema para hacer que una imagen ocupe el 100% de el ancho de la página; acá les muestro el código HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="slider">
        <div id="contenedor">
            <img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg">
            <img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg">
            <img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg">
            <img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Acá el CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#contenedor{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;

}

#contenedor img{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative;
}

#slider{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
```

Pero sucede que no me ocupa todo el ancho de la página, si no que ocupa alrededor de un 75%, solo me lo hace cuando cambio su posición a "absolute" , pero están en un flex y se colocan una sobre otra. No he intentado nada en js porque supongo que se puede solucionar perfectamente en css.

En la anterior imagen, se ve cómo ocupa el 75% la primera imagen y la siguiente se asoma: lo que busco es que ocupe ese espacio rayado en rojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes, es que estás dándole a cada imagen el 100% del ancho de la pantalla. Lo que debes hacer es reducir el tamaño del contenedor de cada imagen. Además por temas de dispositivos, te reomcomiendo usar `vw` y `vh` para mejores resultados. (estos ultimos, son un porcentaje del ancho o alto del dispositivo)
Además, para que tus imagenes se vean de mejor modo, usa `object-fit`, para desplegarlas a gusto.

[EJEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/1uxrgcjb/)

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#contenedor{
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;

}

#contenedor img{
    margin: 0;
    width: 25vw;    
    height: 100vh; 
    position: relative;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#slider{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="slider">
        <div id="contenedor">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1280-720-5.jpg">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1280-720-2.jpg">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-1280-720-1.jpg">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-1280-720-10.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Entiendo a lo que te refieres, pero lo que busco es que cada imagen ocupe el ancho de la pantalla, de manera que pueda cambiar entre ellas con un slider y que la siguiente ocupe toda la pantalla, y así

Comment: No mencionaste el problema del slider en la publicacion, el problema era con las imagenes, además falta el código relacionado al slider

Comment: Claro, entiendo la funcionalidad del slider la coloco en el js, pero no consigo hacer que las imagenes ocupen el 100% de la pantalla, es decir cada una el 100% osea basicamente 4 pantallas

Comment: Por eso, agrega tu slider, para replicar tu problema, y ayudarte a resolverlo

Comment: Aun no he hecho el slider, queria colocar las imagenes primero para luego darle la funcionalidad, pero no he podido resolver lo de las imágenes, voy a colocar una foto de la pagina para explicarme mejor

Comment: Claro, lo que sucede es eso, que al colocar width = 100vw se supone que deberia ocupar el 100% de la pantalla, pero no lo hace, o al menos el 100% de su contenedor padre, el cual si esta ocupando el 100%

Comment: No, son las de prueba de windows, su resolucion es 1024x768, pero si pongo su posicion absolute, llegan a ocupar cada una el 100% sin problema, lo que sucede es que se superponen, como si ignoraran el flex

Comment: No logro replicar tu problema amigo, copio tu codigo, pongo imágenes del mismo tamaño, pero nada. Busca como replicar tu codigo, por que el error no lo puedo encontrar

Comment: No te preocupes, la verdad mi codigo esta un poquito desastroso, entiendo que hay librerias para eso, pero quisiera simular una, asi entiendo un poco mejor el funcionamiento

Comment: Te dejo un slider funcional y suerte con el resto. - https://jsfiddle.net/naq8bk7p/

Comment: Gracias bro, intentare descifrar el problema jajaja, cualquier cosa pondre aqui una solucion si es que la encuentro

Comment: Bro, ya encontré, me sirivio mucho tu slider grax

Comment: Agradeceme marcandome como respuesta jaja

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución, no se como funciona, pero lo hace, metí cada imagen en un div, de esa manera le di el tamaño que quería a cada div e hice que cada imagen cubriera todo su contenedor, no termino de comprender el comportamiento de las imágenes pero intentare descifrarlo.

Comment: No hay mayor secreto [las imágenes son elementos en línea y se colocan en fila una a lado de la otra](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elementos_en_l%C3%ADnea) mientras que los div son elementos en bloque y se colocan uno encima del otro abarcando todo el ancho disponible de su etiqueta contenedora

Comment: Pero aun no entiendo porque no podia redimensionar más la imagen mientras estaba fuera del div, es decir por si misma no se redimiensionaba mas a menos que su posicion fuera absolute, pero dentro de un div que ese si me permite establecer un tamaño deseado si podia escalar la imagen como quisiera